# Idempotent Ansible Commands for configuration boolean flags

Tags: ansible

I am having the following ansible task which sets a boolean flag

```
-
  name: Seting up NodeJS
  command: npm config set strict-ssl false
```

While the command is for sure idempotent, `ansible-playbook` does not recognize that, for obvious reasons and hence produces noise in the dry-run report (in particular, I prefer to be told that nothing changed if the strict-ssl flag was already false when running the playbook)

Is it possible to tell Ansible how to check if the flag is already set? Maybe something like:

```
-
  name: Seting up NodeJS
  command: npm config set strict-ssl false
  when: (npm config get strict-ssl) == true
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your idea with `when` is almost there. Read about https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables, then you can do:

```
  tasks:

  - name: npm config get strict-ssl
    command: npm config get strict-ssl
    register: npm_strict_ssl
    changed_when: false

  - name: Setting up NodeJS
    command: npm config set strict-ssl false
    when: "npm_strict_ssl['stdout'] == 'true'"
```

I will also add that the specific settings you want to disable, strict SSL, smells like a very bad idea. Please consider fixing the root cause of the problem instead of lowering down security.

Comment: That is closer to what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing! One thing I do not particularly like is the semantics, in the sense that now the second task is marked as "skipped". Not sure if that can be fixed without (say) writing my own module. But this is the closest to what I was looking for. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the construct

```
- command: npm config set strict-ssl false
  args:
    creates: "{{ lock_file }}"
```

If there is no *lock_file* created by the *command* you might want to run the *command* in a *block* and create a *lock_file* on your own.

As a *lock_file* can be used any file that will be created by the *command*.

Comment: That is an interesting approach, but it is a bit hacky. These lock files would now live around my system, is that correct?

Comment: Well, that's what [Lock files](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch05s09.html) are for.